# Was the FileTypesFilter deprecated in eclipse-cs 5.6 plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I recently noticed that my checkstyle configuration which I thought used to only check .java files was no longer doing so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fileset-config file-format-version="1.2.0" simple-config="false">
    <local-check-config name="My Checks" location="docu/checkstyle/my-checks.xml" type="project" description="My specific Checkstyle checks">
        <additional-data name="protect-config-file" value="false"/>
    </local-check-config>
    <fileset name="all" enabled="true" check-config-name="My Checks" local="true">
        <file-match-pattern match-pattern="." include-pattern="true"/>
    </fileset>
    <filter name="FileTypesFilter" enabled="true">
        <filter-data value="java"/>
    </filter>
</fileset-config>
```

Did they get rid of the "FileTypesFilter"? The [advanced filters docu](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/advanced_filters.html) seems to indicate that this feature is still there and should be more performant than using file sets to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that as well.  I no longer see that option in the GUI either.  Doc says

> One might rightfully ask why this filter exists where you can achieve the very same using file sets. The answer is simple: performance. 
>   Consider you are using the Checkstyle Plugin with a project that contains several 10,000 files. Using only file sets all files (the full project relative path) of the project would be checked against possibly multiple regular expressions. The worst case is that 100,000 or more regular expression checks would be executed to determine if a file needs to be checked or not.

Perhaps this is no longer a concern or it was removed by accident.